# jQuery keydown : Wait for previous event to finish

Tags: jquery, keydown

We are using the following jQuery code for our site:

```
$(document).keydown(function (x) {
    if (x.keycode == 9) {
        // perform some action
    }
})
```

However, the way it currently works is that when you press this key in quick succession, the action does not get performed successively, but rather it ignores any key presses until the current action is completed. We wish to have it so that any additional key presses are queued, and that any key presses made during the action cause the action to be performed as well but only after the last iteration of the action has been performed.

So for example, if you press the key 9 times, the action is performed 9 times, regardless if the action is being performed during the keypress. The way I have it now is that you could press the key 9 times but the action will only be performed n times for n <= 9, because the keypress is not being recognized while the action is performed.

Any ideas?

EDIT: According to Hunter, I need to use some sort of queue to queue the key presses...how would I go about that?

Comment: using your existing code, it will do exactly as you describe if `// perform some action` is written to do that.

Comment: I would suggest to use `x.which`, that works in all browsers. `x.keycode` won't.

Comment: Thanks for the x.which suggestion..unfortunately I'm still getting the same result. The issue is if I quickly press the key twice in succession, the second key press will NOT cause the action to be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

```
var inProgress = false;

$(document).keydown(function (x) {
    if (x.which == 9) {
        if (!inProgress)
        {
            inProgress = true;
            // perform some action
            inProgress = false;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help hunter, but it's not fixing the problematic behaviour. I can still press a key twice in quick succession and the second keypress will not cause the event to be performed while the first keypress is occurring.

Comment: so you want them to queue up? Is that it?

Comment: Yeah basically. If a key is pressed it gets added to a queue. So for every n keypresses, the action should occur n times, regardless of how closely in succession they were pressed. The problem is that if you do just that with the way the code currently is, some key presses will get lost and the action will get performed less than n times, because while the action is occurring, no key presses are registered.

Comment: Yeah, totally understand. I thought this was doing some other process you didn't want to resubmit.